# Рендер шаблона с angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails

Ситуация следующая. Есть страница с большой формой заполнения данных о рабочем месте. Часть параметров формы статическая (например расположение, ответственный), а часть динамическая (например, состав рабочего места: компьютер, монитор, принтер и т.д.). Для заполнения динамических данных использую angularjs. Если пользователь вводит некорректные данные, валидации не проходят и страница обратно рендерится пользователю.

Проблема в том, что на отрендеренной странице отсутствуют динамически созданные элементы, остаются только статические. То есть всё, что было заполнено с помощью angularjs пропадает. Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы на странице сохранялись все данные?

В голову приходят только такие варианты:

1. Использовать render js, но в таком случае в js шаблоне нужно как-то
   добавить данные в контекст ангулара.
2. Передавать данные на сервер json форматом, отвечать соответственно тоже json форматом. Тогда страница не будет перезагружаться и данные не пропадут в случае ошибок. А если запись создалась, редиректить с  помощью javascript на нужную страницу. Только мне это кажется неправильным, так как вся маршрутизация на стороне сервера прописана, а на данной странице редирект будет на стороне клиента производиться.

Comment: Зачем страницу перезагружать? Используй ajax

Comment: (2) ок. Проблем с редиректом не вижу: URL сущности может быть частью ответа на запрос её создания, переход по этому URL может быть частью логики приложения. Выбор инструментов мне видится немножко странным... но ладно, всякое бывает.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо! А в чем странность, можете уточнить?

Comment: В том, что вы делаете на ангуляре нечто, работающее с сервером не только по абстрактному API, но и с плотным участием его рендеринга. Обычно я вижу, что на ангуляре либо делают приложение целиком на клиенте без перезагрузок вообще, либо на ангуляре ничего не делают.